# Using Flowbite React and I cannot import TabsRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowbite

Using Flowbite React, I wanted to add buttons that switch different Tabs - so I looked up the docs and found that i need this code:

```js
'use client';

import { Button, Tabs, TabsRef } from 'flowbite-react';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { HiAdjustments, HiClipboardList, HiUserCircle } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { MdDashboard } from 'react-icons/md';

function Component() {
  const tabsRef = useRef<TabsRef>(null);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
      <Tabs aria-label="Default tabs" style="default" ref={tabsRef} onActiveTabChange={(tab) => setActiveTab(tab)}>
        <Tabs.Item active title="Profile" icon={HiUserCircle}>
          This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Profile tab's associated content</span>.
          Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
          control the content visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Dashboard" icon={MdDashboard}>
          This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Dashboard tab's associated content</span>.
          Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
          control the content visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Settings" icon={HiAdjustments}>
          This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Settings tab's associated content</span>.
          Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
          control the content visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item title="Contacts" icon={HiClipboardList}>
          This is <span className="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Contacts tab's associated content</span>.
          Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to
          control the content visibility and styling.
        </Tabs.Item>
        <Tabs.Item disabled title="Disabled">
          Disabled content
        </Tabs.Item>
      </Tabs>
      <div className="text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Active tab: {activeTab}</div>
      <Button.Group>
        <Button color="gray" onClick={() => tabsRef.current?.setActiveTab(0)}>
          Profile
        </Button>
        <Button color="gray" onClick={() => tabsRef.current?.setActiveTab(1)}>
          Dashboard
        </Button>
        <Button color="gray" onClick={() => tabsRef.current?.setActiveTab(2)}>
          Settings
        </Button>
        <Button color="gray" onClick={() => tabsRef.current?.setActiveTab(3)}>
          Contacts
        </Button>
      </Button.Group>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the problem is, there is no TabsRef in flowbite-react... Gives me this (obvious) error:
`export 'TabsRef' (imported as 'TabsRef') was not found in 'flowbite-react'`

I tried updating the package, searching the internet, but the search literally yielded no results.
I cannot find anybody on the internet having this problem... Is there a workaround?

I also tried importing the file directly, which went as follows:

Tabs.d.ts:

```
export interface TabsRef {
 setActiveTab: (activeTab: number) => void;
}
```

Error in console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/components/Tabs/Tabs.d.ts?v=d7f38b6c' does not provide an export named 'TabsRef' (at Cart.jsx:3:10)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving any errors to me maybe you have not installed the `flowbite` and `flowbite-react` packages properly , you also need to configure the `tailwind.config.js`. Follow the instructions from the [Flowbite Installation](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/react/)

Here are my results:

Output:
[image: Result]

Code:
[image: React code]

Comment: It's configured properly...

Comment: Can you share you configuration details